# Template specialization error in Solaris

Tags: c++, templates, solaris, sfinae

Following code compiles in Linux and Aix but not on Sun solaris version 5.12 c++ compiler. Any suggestion, how to make it work?

```
template <class T>
struct SpecTemp 
{
};

template <class T>
struct UnspecTemp 
{
   typedef T type;
};
struct TestType {};
template <>
struct SpecTemp<TestType> 
{
   typedef TestType type;
};

template <>
struct UnspecTemp<TestType> 
{
};

template <class Hello>
typename SpecTemp<Hello>::type test(Hello help) 
{ 
    return help;
}

 template <class Hello>
 typename UnspecTemp<Hello>::type test(Hello help) 
 { 
     return help;   
 }

 template <>
 TestType test(TestType) 
 { 
    return TestType();
 }

 int main() 
 {
     TestType a = {};
     test(a);
 }
```

This is a bug in solaris compiler. error is as follows:

```
"main.cpp", line 32: Error: type is not a member of UnspecTemp<TestType>.
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: *This is a bug in solaris compiler.* Don't be so sure.  It's just as likely a bug in GCC if that's the only other compiler you've tested this code under.  What *exact* version of the Solaris compiler are you using?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Looks like a bug to me. SFINAE literally means Substitution Failure Is Not An Error. To this compiler, Substitution Failure Is An Error. The correct behavior is to silently eliminate one of the two overloads.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: solaris compiler version is 5.12. The code works in Linux and AIX